# Cassandara as Database for Complex System

Tags: cassandra

Can Cassandra be used for complex system for.e.g Accounting like System? My client is looking for Big Data solution for one of the projects and he proposes to use Cassandra . Some of the questions I have in mind are

1. Does it support JTA transactions ? If not JTA then does it support
   normal transactions?
2. How flexible is it to define database model of
   accounting like system where we will require some sort of relational
   model.
3. Any other pros and cons you would like to highlight ? Based
   on documentation I can see its easy to scale.

Comment: Please define what "JTA" is (java transaction api perhaps?) and provide a bit of background in your original question. If you have a idea of the schema, and how you need to scale this and the expected SLA (read / writes per second) and the amount of data storage / lifetime / delete frequency - this will all be a factor and will allow people to give more informed answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to use anything just for sake of using, first read about Cassandra and based on your use case make wise decision.

Cassandra is eventual consistent, but for accounting system you need ACID properties, which is not supported by cassandra. Also cassandra transactions are different from RDBMS transactions. It support row level & each partition atomicity.
Consider if you need to transfer money from account A to B. which are part of two different partitions, it will be difficult to maintain consistency.

Comment: thanks. Yes I am already reading about Cassndra, however it will take some time to understand it fully and hence i wanted feedback from people on this forum. The main reason why client proposed cassandra is becuase they are looking for big data solution as backend for their system but at the same time I am concerned if other requirements will be met.

Comment: Just to comment here, there are LWTs (light weight transactions) in cassandra which do provide transaction "locking" as such but you do need to make sure your client specs things out clearly before you even start to think about the technology you're going to underpin it all